# Python | Aiogram | повторное отправление сообщений

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio, aiogram

Столкнулся с такой ситуацией, которую к сожалению не могу победить.
Написан бот, который проверяет "изменения" из выписки ЕГРН, через `requests`.

Если запускать скрипт отдельно, то отрабатывает на 100 процентов. Но вот если данный скрипт начинает работать в боте, то возникают такие ситуации, когда сообщения о статусе дублируются (не сразу, а со временем), и по одной фирме в чат приходят 3-4 сообщения одинаково содержания.

```
async def zzz(wait_for: int, coro):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(wait_for)
        await coro()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
   Block = Blocker()
   Check = Checker()
   loop.create_task(zzz(900, coro = Block.run_all))
   loop.create_task(zzz(1700 coro = Check.main))
   execute.start_polling(dp,loop = loop)
```

Блоки `Block` и  `Checker` это как раз сами проверки. Один проверяет на наличие блокировки фирмы, второй проверяет на наличие изменении в выписки ЕГРН.

Ниже представлен метод получения токенов:

```
async def get_token(self, proxy, inn):
    if len(str(inn)) == 10:
        params = {"page": "1", "pageSize": "10", "pbCaptchaToken": "", "token": "", "mode": "search-all", "queryAll": str(inn), "queryUl": "", "okvedUl": "", "statusUl": "", "regionUl": "", "isMspUl": "", "mspUl1": "1", "mspUl2": "2", "mspUl3": "3", "queryIp": "", "okvedIp": "", "statusIp": "", "regionIp": "", "isMspIp": "", "mspIp1": "1", "mspIp2": "2", "mspIp3": "3", "queryUpr": "","uprType1": "1","uprType0": "1", "queryRdl": "", "dateRdl": "", "queryAddr": "", "regionAddr": "", "queryOgr": "", "ogrFl": "1", "ogrUl": "1", "npTypeDoc": "1", "ogrnUlDoc": "", "ogrnIpDoc": "","nameUlDoc": "","nameIpDoc": "","formUlDoc": "","formIpDoc": "","ifnsDoc": "","dateFromDoc": "","dateToDoc": ""}
        try:
            async with httpx.AsyncClient(headers=self.__headers, proxies=f'http://{proxy}') as client:
                response = await client.post(self.__url_token, params=params)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    r = response.json()
                    await self.fetch_token(r)
                else:
                    await self.__rotate_proxy()
                    await self.get_token(proxy=self._proxy, inn=inn)

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f'ОШИБКА|{proxy}|{inn}|{e}')
            try:
                await self.__rotate_proxy()
                async with httpx.AsyncClient(headers=self.__headers, proxies=f'http://{self._proxy}') as client:
                    response = await client.get(self.__url_token, params=self.__params)
                    r = response.json()
                    await self.fetch_token(r)
            except:
                pass
```

Это метод получения уже самой информации, которая мне необходима:

```
    async def data_for_token(self, proxy, token):
        params2 = {'token': str(token)}
        try:
            async with httpx.AsyncClient(proxies=f'http://{proxy}') as client:
                response2 = await client.post(self.__url_check, params=params2)
                if response2.status_code == 200:
                    e = response2.json()
                    await self.check_changes(e)
                else:
                    await self.__rotate_proxy()
                    logger.warning(f'Повторное отправление {token}')
                    await self.data_for_token(proxy=self._proxy, token=token)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Ну и собственно сам вывод информации в телеграмм бот

```
 @staticmethod
 async def check_changes(res: dict):

        data = res.get('vyp')
        name_firm = data.get('НаимЮЛПолн')
        inn = data.get('ИНН')
        mes = None
        try:
            if 'СвНедАдресЮЛ' in data:
                info = data.get('СвНедАдресЮЛ')[0]
                mes = f'Название:{name_firm}\nИНН:{inn}\n\tТекст:<b>СВЕДЕНИЯ О НЕДОСТОВЕРНОСТИ ДАННЫХ ОБ АДРЕСЕ ' \

            if 'СведДолжнФЛ' in data:
                info = data.get('СведДолжнФЛ')[0]
                sugn = info.get('СвНедДанДолжнФЛ')[0]
                mes = f'Название:{name_firm}\nИНН:{inn}\n\tТекст:<b>СВЕДЕНИЯ О НЕДОСТОВЕРНОСТИ ДАННЫХ О РУКОВОДИТЕЛЕ ' \
                      f'КОМПАНИИ</b>\n\t{sugn.get("ТекстНедДанДолжнФЛ")}\n\tДата записи:{sugn.get("ДатаЗаписи")}'
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=xxx, text=mes)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

Прошу прощения, если написан много не нужной информации. Постарался максимально изложить всю суть проблемы.
Подскажите куда надо копать, и как это можно исправить?

Comment: @violet спасибо большое что отредактировал сообщение.

Comment: Запятых ещё не хватает

Comment: А у тебя сообщения повторяются с данными того же юзера или идут в разнос по разным чатам?
Возможно у тебя проблема с хранилищем